# keyerror while tring to access pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to process create a pandas dataframe column and access the column by using its column name which gives an error `KeyError: 'cluster'`

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fclusterdata

max_dist = 3
points = [(3, 2), (6, 2), (6, 5), (10, 1), (12, -2), (5, 7)]
clusters = fclusterdata(points, t=max_dist, criterion='distance')
clustered_points = (pd.DataFrame(points, columns=['x', 'y'], index=clusters)
                      .rename_axis(index='cluster'))
clustered_points['cluster']
```

How this error can be solved.

Comment: `cluster` is your index name which it appears you intentionally named as such.  You could do: `clustered_points.reset_index()['cluster']` or go the route that @PrestigeDev suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import pandas as pd
    from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fclusterdata
    
    max_dist = 3
    points = [(3, 2), (6, 2), (6, 5), (10, 1), (12, -2), (5, 7)]
    clusters = fclusterdata(points, t=max_dist, criterion='distance')
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(points, columns=['x', 'y'])
    df["clusters"] = clusters
    print(df["clusters"])
```

If you're trying to access the column "clusters" I think this is the way to do it.